# How to use a relational database to store all users who belong to a group, and all groups which a user belongs to?

Tags: database-design, relational-theory

This is a beginner question:

A user can belong to many groups, and a group can contain many users.

Let's say the two tables look something like this:

user_id
user_name
user_email

group_id
group_title
group_description

Where and how do I store all of the users which belong to a group and all the groups a user belongs to?

I can't imagine the groups table having a users field which contains comma separated user IDs being an acceptable solution. I think I get the basic concept of relational databases, but I'm not sure of the implementation. I get the one-to-one relationship, but I'm struggling with one-to-many. Is what I'm dealing with in this example two separate one-to-many relationships?

Comment: This is a many-to-many relationship you have, usually implemented with an intermediate table, as JNK's answer, that has one-to-many relationships with the two other (User and Group) tables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want three tables for this:

- `Users` with a row per user and whatever details you need
- `Groups` with a row per group and whatever details you need
- `UsersGroups` with a unique combination of `UserId, GroupId` that only keeps track of relationships

This will let you have as many combinations as you like.

Comment: Thank you for answering. How would the UsersGroups table look like though? If we have user 001 who belongs to groups 001 002 003 would that be 3 rows in the UsersGroups table? Should each row in the UsersGroups table have a unique ID? Why?

Comment: I prefer single names for tables. UserGroup table will be: (UserID, GroupID, any other information related to the association). In this case, UserID + GroupID represent the Primary Key. You could also use a separate ID column but you must have the User+GroupID as a unique constraint in all cases.

Comment: @bernk Yes, one row per relation.  And you don't really need another key here, since you will want a unique constraint or PK on the combination of `UserId, GroupId` to prevent duplicates.

Comment: @JNK By "unique constraint or PK" do you mean that I should check the data at some point before storing it in the DB to make sure that this pair of UserId and GroupId doesn't already exist? If so, should I do this before with PHP or within MySQL? Thanks for the gentle treatment of a n00b (me).

Comment: @bernk: With MySQL, you can do it without checking before, by using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` (if you want to do some updating when the combination already exists), or `INSERT IGNORE ...` (if you want to do nothing when the combination already exists).

Comment: Or instead of `INSERT INTO t(UserID, GroupID) VALUES (2, 7);` use an `INSERT INTO t(UserID, GroupID) SELECT 2, 7 FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t WHERE UserID=2 AND GroupID=7);`

Comment: I was referring to making that combination either a `PK` or putting a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on those fields to enforce uniqueness within the database.

Comment: This is getting a bit away from my original question, but… Let's say I'm making an event planning app. Each event has some basic data about it like its title, location, description, etc. Each event also has a list of participants, a creator, comments, lists, groups, etc. As an example, would it be correct to make a (potentially) giant table for listevent which would contain ALL the lists created in the app and the ID of the event they belong to? …what about the items in each of those lists?! Would they go in an even more giant table which would hold items and their list ID? Am I totally off?

Comment: @bernk: You are right that this is getting away from the original question. It would be better to make a basic design that you think that fits your purpose and post another question (on how it can improved or if there are flaws)